# How to exclude Hystrix Metrics from the Actuator /metrics endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring-boot-app with Actuator and Hystrix enabled.
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.3.1.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I add `@HystrixCommand`to some methods, the `/metrics` Endpoint shows all the metrics from hystrix:

```
gauge.hystrix.HystrixCommand.RestEndpoints.TestController.test.errorPercentage: 0,
gauge.hystrix.HystrixThreadPool.RestEndpoints.rollingMaxActiveThreads: 1,
...
```

**Question:**
How can I exclude the hystrix-metrics completely from the `/metrics`endpoint?

---

**Update 1**
I tried to exclude the ServoMetrics and SpectatorMetrics with these approaches:

1)

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={ServoMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
 SpectatorMetricsAutoConfiguration.class} )
```

2)

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={ServoMetricServices.class, SpectatorMetricServices.class})
```

But both did not achieved the desired effect.

Comment: There is currently not a way to exclude them unless you exclude `com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream` from your dependencies which will also cause the `/hystrix.stream` to stop working as well.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for clarification. Too bad... That could be worth a feature request...

Comment: done, see my new answer.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you a thousand times!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/781) was created and fixed. In snapshots you can now set the following:
`hystrix.metrics.enabled=false`.

Comment: it is not very straightforward to set this parameter effectively in Spring code/configuration. But setting it as system variable works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any other metrics, better solution would be to create your own MetricsRegistry. This way, any other future code changes (adding more jars with more in built metrics) would not affect.

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfiguration {

  private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

  MetricsConfiguration() {
    //avoid other metrics already registered
    metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry();
  }

}
```

Note: Creating a @Bean of type MetricRegistry would not help, as Spring autoconfigure will use this Bean object instead of `MetricsRegistry object from MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration.java`